# Is it possible to make a youtube html5 video go fullscreen (in iOS) by injecting call to click the onClick button?

Tags: jquery, ios, html, youtube-api, html5-video

In my iOS program I´m running a webView where I load up the youtube.com website (not just a standalone video on my html page).

There I have my own controls (buttons) on the side where **I would like to "click" the fullscreen button with JQuery** (witch I have injected into the webView.

This is the button I´m trying to "click" with JQuery

```
 <button type="button" class="html5-fullscreen-button html5-control-right ytp-tooltip-anchor hid yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-player yt-uix-button-empty" onclick=";return false;" tabindex="15" data-value="fullscreen" data-tooltip-default="Full screen" data-tooltip="Full screen" data-tooltip-alt="Exit full screen" role="button" aria-label="Full screen">
```

And this is the JQuery I tried to use to "click" to go to fullscreen.

```
$('.html5-fullscreen-button').click();
```

This is how I click it from a iOS button (I also tried to

```
[self.watchView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"theJqueryFindFullscreenClickFunction"];
```

Here is the full html/Jquery http://jsfiddle.net/sturla76/G6GdV/6/ to play with.

**So a recap:**

1. How to click iOS button with Jquery?
2. Is it possible that iOS (IPhone/IPad) is stopping/banning the "click"?
3. If stopping/banned does anybody know how to get the html5 player
   into a webview-fullscreen (not device fullscreen)? Maybe with CSS?

**My specs:**
I´m running JQuery mobile 1.3.1, iOS 6.1 on a IPad 2.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. I can't speak for any unique quirks of webview precisely, but the following will apply to Mobile Safari.

Assuming you're embedding the YouTube player as an iframe, you cannot reach into it to force a click event on that button or even access the button at all. This is because of cross-origin security restrictions built into the browser/DOM.

However, you can fake it by making the iframe element itself display at full screen. Many desktop browsers support the [Full Screen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode), which you can use to make any element on a web page fullscreen. iOS doesn't support that, but you can work around it by resizing the iframe to full 100% height and width of the page (make sure you set "position: absolute").

There is one more trick you need to worry about though, which is that once you resize the iframe, you need to tell YouTube to resize the video and control elements inside it. You can do that with YouTube's iframe API. You can find instructions on how to get that set up [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started), and use the `setSize` method with the dimensions of the iframe when you enter and exit full screen.

Comment: The thing is that im not embedding the player. Im just opening up the youtube e.g http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vy1KhbEpVCY and trying to simulate clicking the fullscreen button of the player. Im not even sure how i would resize the player with css. But you are probably right with "cross-roigin security restrictions" but Ill mark this correct if somebody else doesn´t shine in couple of days. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I see. You could point the webView to the iframe source, like this: http://www.youtube.com/embed/Vy1KhbEpVCY But you'd lose the current play state. See the YT docs for query params on that URL.

Comment: Ahhh..... ok Im going to try that and see if i manage to press play also through javascript. Will mark this as an answer if it works, because that would full fill my need.

Comment: Thanks and good luck. Please update here what you end up using.